# Line break <br> in xml discarded in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am doing XSL transformation on an xml document which has a structure as below.

```
<text_collection>
    <text key="score_1"> Score 1 <br/> Good.  </text>
    <text key="score_2"> Score 2 <br/> Poor.  </text>
</text_collection>
```

My XSLT is simple which is

```
<xsl:template mode="codes" match="text">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

But the issue I am facing is that when the HTML is created the `<br/>` is missing. In the document, I get only

```
<ul>
     <li> Score 1 Good. </li>
     <li> Score 2 Poor. </li>
  </ul>
```

Could anyone please let me know why is the `<br/>` discarded?

Thanks..

Comment: Sorry guys the line break 'br' was missed in the question. the Line break '<br>' is missing after the transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

use:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
```

This will transfer both text and element nodes to the output tree.

Answer (score 1):

`xsl:value-of` copies your text, but won't copy the nested elements in it.

For example, you could do this (to achieve a line break AFTER all the text you previously selected.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="./br"/>
```

But it would be useless, as you might as well write:

```
<br/>
```

directly in your document.

I would look at restructuring your XML document, if possible. You could add `<Lines>` under your `<text>` elements. You can then get the `value:of` each line and follow it by a line break as necessary.

Comment: "*I would look at restructuring your XML document*" That's not necessary. XSLT is perfectly capable of handling any XML document.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I've been working with XSLT off and on for years, but I completely forgot about node(). Your solution below is the right answer.